# Optimising table assignment to guests for an event based on a criteria

Tags: optimization, permutation, np-hard

66 guests at an event, 8 tables.  Each table has a "theme".  We want to optimize various criteria: e.g., even number of men/women at the table, people get to discuss the topic they selected, etc.

I formulated this as a gradient-free optimisation problem: I wrote a function that calculates the goodness of the arrangement (i.e., cost of difference of men women, cost of non-preferred theme, etc.) and I am basically randomly perturbing the arrangement by swapping tables and keeping the "best so far" arrangement.  This seems to work, but cannot guarantee optimality.

I am wondering if there is a more principled way to go about this.  There (intuitively) seems to be no useful gradient in the operation of "swapping" people between tables, so random search is the best I came up with.  However, brute-forcing by evaluating *all* possibilities seems to be difficult; if there are 66 people, there are factorial(66) possible orders, which is a ridiculously large number (10^92 according to Python).  Since swapping two people at the same table is the same, there are actually fewer, which I *think* can be calculated by dividing out the repeats, e.g. fact(66)/(fact(number of people at table 1) * fact(number of people at table 2) * ...), which in my problem still comes out to about 10^53 possible arrangements, way too many to consider.

But is there something better that I can do than random search?  I thought about evolutionary search but I don't know if it would provide any advantages.

Currently I am swapping a random number of people on each evaluation and keeping it only if it gives a better value.  The random number of people is selected from an exponential distribution to make it more probable to swap 1 person than 6, for example, to make small steps on average but to keep the possibility of "jumping" a bit further in the search.

I don't know how to prove it but I have a feeling this is an NP-hard problem; if that's the case, how could it be reformulated for a standard solver?

Update: I have been comparing random search with a random "greedy search" and a "simulated annealing"-inspired approach where I have a probability of keeping swaps based on the measured improvement factor, that anneals over time.  So far the greedy search surprisingly strongly outperforms the probabilistic approach.  Adding the annealing schedule seems to help.

What I am confused by is exactly how to think about the "space" of the domain.  I realize that it is a discrete space, and that distance are best described in terms of Levenshtein edit distance, but I can't think how I could "map" it to some gradient-friendly continuous space.  Possibly if I remove the exact number of people-per-table and make this continuous, but strongly penalize it to incline towards the number that I want at each table -- this would make the association matrix more "flexible" and possibly map better to a gradient space?  Not sure.  Seating assignment could be a probability spread over more than one table..

Comment: What is the form of the cost function? This strongly affects the available options

Comment: It's a sum of absolute differences that I am minimizing.  How does it affect the available options?  Perhaps I can change it if there is a better way to express the cost.

Comment: Can't you reduce the number of combinations as the order of tables is not important, should reduce the number by a factor 8!

Comment: Taking into account that the order of people at each table does not matter, the problem reduces from 10^92 to 10^53.  You're right about the table order, but taking it into account does not change the size of the problem much.  I am not sure if it should reduce by a factor of 8 or a factor of factorial(8), but the first means it is still about 10^53, and the latter means it goes to 10^49, still an astronomical number of permutations to check.

Comment: I will add that after trying a few algorithms I am quite satisfied with my greedy random permutation search.  It finds an answer quite quickly and after about 3000 iterations the improvements drop exponentially.  I can get ever so slightly better results after 300,000 iterations, but it barely makes a difference.  So greedy random search wins here.  I compared with simulated annealing, but it surprisingly performs worse.